# Decide Trustworthiness Of Statements About Probabilities

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

This is maybe a trivial question, but I don't know the answer right now.  Assume you have $n$ coins, each with probability $P_i$ of landing on head.  You don't know the probabilities, but there are $m$ agents $A^j$ who claim that the $i$th coin lands on head with probability $P^j_i$.  You are only allowed to toss each coin exactly once.  Assume you want to somehow decide how trustworthy the agents are.  Which scoring function $s:2^n\times[0,1]^n\to\mathbf{R}$ (input tossing result and claimed probabilities, output score) would you use?

Some properties I imagine the scoring function should have:

- $E(s(-,(P'_i)_i))<E(s(-,(P_i)_i))$ for $(P'_i)_i\neq (P_i)_i$
- $P(s(-,(P'_i)_i)<s(-,(P_i)_i))>0.5$ for $(P'_i)_i\neq (P_i)_i$

First thing which comes to mind is computing the probability that the observed tosses occur under the given probability distribution.

Comment: One way to do it:  Trusting that $n$ is large you might imagine that you bet fairly on each coin.  That is you imagine that if coin $i$ comes up $H$ you get $1-p_i$ and that you lose $p_i$ if it comes up $T$.  This is a bet with expectation $0$ (trusting the predictions).  I would look at the payout for the given results and see if it is consistent with expectation $0$.

Comment: To elaborate a bit:  it is tedious to compute the variance of my bet analytically (for general $p_i$) but it is easy to simulate.  So I'd start by computation this by simulation.  Then you can set your confidence threshhold (for rejecting the fairness of the bet) using the $\sigma$ you compute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah, that makes sense!